# How to implement a onMenuItemClickListener in android

Tags: android

How do I implement an `onMenuItemClickListener`?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gameoptions, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item).setIntent(new Intent(this, QMenuActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.back_item).setOnMenuItemClickListener;
    return true;
}
```

I want the back_item once clicked on to call a function within the page, how do I do it?

Comment: Reformat your question, there is no way that your current source will compile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to access a non-static function in your activity.  Without too much information from you, try something like what's below:

```java
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.back_item);
    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            YourActivity.this.someFunctionInYourActivity();
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener()
```

change the code to include `MenuItem` after new.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the onOptionsItemSelected as well

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gameoptions, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item).setIntent(new Intent(this, QMenuActivity.class));
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.back_item:
            // Call your function here
            yourFunction();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void yourFunction() {
    // Your function's code here
}
```