# how do i implement setonmenuitemclicklistener?

Tags: java, android

i am trying following code

```
@Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

            // same as using a normal menu

            switch(item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.refresh_acti:
                MenuItem it = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.refresh_acti);
                it.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
                    }
                });

               // makeToast("Refreshing...");

                break;

            case R.id.setting_lay:

                makeToast("Saving...");

                break;

            }



            return true;

        }
```

but...
 `it.setonmenuitemclicklistner` give the following error.

> The method
>   `setOnMenuItemClickListener(MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener)` in the
>   type `MenuItem` is not applicable for the  arguments `(new
>   OnMenuItemClickListener(){})`

Comment: probably it via MenuItem it = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.refresh_acti); is not really a MenuItem?

Comment: There's at least two classes called `OnMenuItemClickListener`: one in `MenuItem`, one in `PopupMenu`. Look at your imports, which one are you importing? Might be the one from `PopupMenu`.

Comment: i am importing Menu not PopMenu.. Philipp Reichart

Comment: yes it is 'MenuItem' @Stan

Comment: Are you using ActionBarSherlock? There might be import confusion because of that as well.

Comment: No i am using Actionbar.

Comment: You might have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691788/how-to-implement-a-onmenuitemclicklistener-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case id_1:
        Log.d("Log","ID 1 PRESSED");
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```